# How do I position a div after a div or at the bottom depending the window size? (image example)

Tags: css, positioning, html

I want a div to be below its sibling, if the browser window is big enough or
to be at the bottom. The div1 doesn't have a static height of course.

This image is how I want to position div2 if the browser window is big

[image: big window]

The following is how I want div2 to be positioned if the browser window is small.

[image: small window]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing a "[sticky footer](http://www.google.com/search?q=sticky+footer)".

- http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/
- http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/